# Counting the highlighted cells in html table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to count the number of selected cells (clicked cells in **each row**), and show the count in a cell on the right of table.

The code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('td').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selectedCell");
  });
});

function update_counts() {
  $('.tdoutput').html('');
  $('.row').each(function(index) {
    $('.tdoutput').html($('.tdoutput').html() + $(this).find('.selectedCell').length + ' selected cells ');
  });
}

$('.td').click(function() {
  // Add or remove class
  $(this).toggleClass('selectedCell');
  // Update the class counts
  update_counts();

});

// Run the function on domready
$(function() {
  update_counts();
});
```

```css
.selectedCell {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="tdoutput"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="tdoutput"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to adapt a code, but I couldn't make it work. Can I get a little help to make it work please? thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for great answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. You need the context of the `$('.tdoutput')` instance relative to the specific row using either context argument or `$(this).find('.tdoutput')` inside the rows loop.

```js
function update_counts() {

  $('.row').each(function(index) {
    $('.tdoutput', this).html($(this).find('.selectedCell').length + ' selected cells ');
                // ^^^ only in this row
  });
}



// Run the function on domready
$(function() {
  update_counts();

  $('td').click(function() {
    // Add or remove class
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedCell');
    // Update the class counts
    update_counts();

  });
});
```

```css
.selectedCell {
  background-color: green;
}
td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="tdoutput"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="tdoutput"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this:

Use `td` with `closest` and `tr` with `find` to implement this behaviour.

```js
$(function() {
  $("table tr").each(function() {
    update_counts($(this));
  });
});

function update_counts($tr) {
  var count = $tr.find('.selectedCell').length;
  $tr.find('.tdoutput').html(count + " selected");
}

$('td').click(function() {
  // Add or remove class
  $(this).toggleClass('selectedCell');
  // Update the class counts
  update_counts($(this).closest("tr"));

});
```

```css
.selectedCell {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="tdoutput"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="tdoutput"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

add `update_counts();` in first code of script and remove `.td click` code

```js
$(function() {
  $('td').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selectedCell");
    update_counts(); // add here
  });
});


function update_counts() {
  $('.tdoutput').html('');
  $('.row').each(function(index) {
    //console.log($(this).find('.selectedCell').length, index, 'test');
    $('.tdoutput').html($('.tdoutput').html() + $(this).find('.selectedCell').length + ' selected cells ');
  });
}

// Run the function on domready
$(function() {
  update_counts();
});
```

```css
.selectedCell {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="tdoutput"></td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="tdoutput"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Doubt this is the expected behavior

Comment: what you have doubt @charlietfl

Comment: `$('.tdoutput').html()` always gets value of first row only and you are making all rows render same

Comment: i have only update user question, not to try best way code because user has confuse with new code and not understand how to work? @charlietfl. so first thing is how user get his question answer on his way not our way

Comment: *"clicked cells in each row"* ... not complicated

Comment: i cant understand what you say?

Answer (score 1):

here is the working fiddle. I hope I have manage to help you. Slight change in script only.

```
<script>
$( function() {
  $('td').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selectedCell");
    var numItems = $('.selectedCell').length
    $('.tdoutput').html(numItems +" Selected")
    });
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s73gv6zt/1/

Answer (score 1):

Change your JS to:

```
function update_counts()
{
    // Clear output
    $('.tdoutput').html('');
    // Each rows,
     $('.row').each(function(index,rowObject){
         // Count has .selectedCell in this row
         var count = $(rowObject).find('td.selectedCell').length;
         // Write to this row output.
         $(rowObject).find('td.tdoutput').html( count + ' selected cells ');
     });  
}

$('td').click(function(){
  // Add or remove class
  $(this).toggleClass('selectedCell');

  // Update the class counts
  update_counts();
}); 



// Run the function on domready 
$(function(){
   update_counts();
});
```